# How to fix a CSV where the variable names are in each row in R

Tags: r, csv, data-cleaning

I'm currently trying to work with this file: https://vote.nyc/sites/default/files/pdf/election_results/2021/20211102General%20Election/00000200000Citywide%20Mayor%20Citywide%20EDLevel.csv

The way the file is written has the variable names with the corresponding values in the same row, as in

> "AD","ED","County","EDAD Status","Event","Party/Independent Body","Office/Position Title","District Key","VoteFor","Unit Name","Tally","65","001","New York","IN-PLAY","General Election 2021 - 11/02/2021",,"Mayor","NYC",1,"Public Counter",160
> "AD","ED","County","EDAD Status","Event","Party/Independent Body","Office/Position Title","District Key","VoteFor","Unit Name","Tally","65","001","New York","IN-PLAY","General Election 2021 - 11/02/2021",,"Mayor","NYC",1,"Manually Counted Emergency",0

and so on.

How do we convert this to normal dataframe format in R?

Comment: Please post a 2 or 3 rows and 2 or 3 columns in your question so we don't have to download a file to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- read.csv("https://vote.nyc/sites/default/files/pdf/election_results/2021/20211102General%20Election/00000200000Citywide%20Mayor%20Citywide%20EDLevel.csv")%>%
  select(-c(1:11))

colnames(x) <- c("AD","ED","County","EDAD Status","Event","Party/Independent Body","Office/Position Title","District Key","VoteFor","Unit Name","Tally")
```